# Good microscope?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, microbiology, microscopy

Hi I am a teenager and I recently studied biology and found it very interesting. I want to get a microscope and study further into the microscopic world. What would be the best microscope for me? I would like to see the cells in living organisms. I am willing to spend about $200 as well.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. What are you interested in observing? Do you want to be able to see individual cells? See bacteria?

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple of things you should ask yourself:

a) how 'small' do you want to see
b) what are you trying to study - (microspores can differ depending on that. Examples: Microbiology - (bacteriology), Plant biology...)

200 dollars for a 'proper prof. microscope'I do not think is enough. However I do not think that is what you are looking for (For example, the one I use in the lab is around 1,200$, and it is not even the best) However, I think this microspore will be good for a beginner home one:  http://www.microscopenet.com/40x2000x-amscope-binocular-biological-compound-microscope-p-10436.html?osCsid=l26ecpfe9nfvbvr306ddvbca14

I think this would be your best fit for the type of microscope you are looking for, however you can look around to see if you can find it for a better deal.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky and live in a university town with student shops, which are run by student organizations, I would recommend you to visit one of those shops.

Often they sell used microscopes, which are no longer needed. If you do not mind that these microscopes have been used before, you will get a much better quality for less money.

If you go to such a shop by yourself as a teenager, and tell them how eager you are about learning biology, I guess that they would not hesitate to sell you a good microscope for little money.